# Sidewall damage on run flats from curb. Do I need to replace the tire?

Tags: tires, bmw, sidewall-damage

I just replaced all 4 run flats on my BMW less than 2 weeks ago.

This afternoon while parking, we ran into part of the curb that is sticking out from the recent rain/flooding, which I hadn’t noticed.

We were moving pretty slow, but I managed to scrape up the rim a bit and took a chunk out of the sidewall. I’d prefer not to replace this tire again, since it has less than 100 miles on it, but I will if it’s a safety concern.

Is this safe to drive on? It’s the back passenger side for context.

[image: tiredamage]

[image: tiredamage2]

[image: tiredamage3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damage you show is to the rim protector built into the tire - and it seems to have helped to minimise damage to the rim.

If the damage is as is shown and there is no crevice or hole going deeper then yes it is fine to drive on - But do keep an eye on it - separation, cracking, bulging will mean replacement.

Comment: I had the tire inspected by the dealer and everything looks okay. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to gauge the actual damage from the pictures. In some cases we have tried portable x-ray machines. Now without getting in to a debate of whether or not there is threatening damage. My recommendation is you claim warranty on one tire, and the dealer has an option to give you 50% discount as a Good will gesture towards the purchase of a replacement, since it is not a defect and rather self inflicted damage.